# После установки обновлений на Windows-10 стал виден резервный диск

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10, файловая-система, диск

Введение в проблему:

Есть ноутбук ACER Pentium четырехъядерный довольно новый (CPU N3540 покупал два с половиной года назад). На нем стояла Windows-8 после покупки она проапгрейдилась до Windows-10-64 Home Edition. Windows-10-64 периодически качает обновления. **СЕГОДНЯ** поставилось очередное обновление. Теперь система показывает версию Windows 10 Version 1803 и номер сборки 17134.81.

В системе есть 4 диска:

C:\ - системный

D:\ - DVD-RW накопитель

E:\ - съемный механический USB винт от Трансенд

F:\ - съемный механический USB винт от Трансенд

Но не все оказалось так уж хорошо. После установки этого последнего обновления проявился новый диск G:\ размером 471 **МЕГА**байта. На этом диске занято 423 МБ и свободно 48 Мб. При внимательном рассмотрении выяснилось, что скорее всего это внутренний винт, на котором при поставке была записана копия Windows-8. На этом диске G:\ находятся три папки:

1. $RECYCLE.BIN размер 129 байт
2. Recovery размер 0 байт
3. System Volume Information размер 0 байт

Все папки недоступны.

Вопросы:

1. Это что, теперь больше нельзя будет восстановить исходную Windows-8 с резервного диска?
2. В связи с вопросом п. 1 теперь надо отформатировать этот диск G:\ и использовать его как еще один накопитель? Или его не надо трогать и он нужен для каких-то таинственных действий системы?
3. Где физически находится этот диск G:\? на диске C:\ или это какая-то флешка в ноутбуке?
4. В связи с вопросом п. 2 и  п. 3 можно ли как-то присоединить этот диск G:\ с диску C:\ или он так и будет болтаться в системе как отдельный накопитель?
5. Еще одна неприятная особенность: в начале работы секунд через десять после включения появляется сообщение о том, что этот диск G:\ переполнен и предлагается очистить лишние файлы на нем. Появляется панель очистки где все лишние файлы показаны как нулевые. Если согласиться и нажать ОК, то панель пропадает и больше не появляется до следующего перезапуска машины. Как сделать, чтобы это сообщение не появлялось?

Спасибо.

Comment: В вопросе должен быть только 1 вопрос, а не целых 5.

Comment: [В вопросе должен быть только 1 вопрос, а не целых 5.] И что же, мне надо задать 5 вопросов с одной и той же преамбулой?